# Spanish Characters in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly, utf

I am currently working on a Spanish translation program that uses HtmlDocument to access the Google translate website. I am programming in Assembly C# in Unity. Shown below is my current code for accessing Google:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using HtmlAgilityPack;


public class Dictionary{
    string[] formatParams;
    HtmlDocument doc;
    string returnString;
    char[] letters;
    public Dictionary(){
        formatParams = new string[2];
        doc = new HtmlDocument();
        returnString = "";
    }
    public string Translate(String input, String languagePair, Encoding encoding)
    {
        formatParams[0]= input;
        formatParams[1]= languagePair;
        string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", formatParams);

        string result = String.Empty;

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Encoding = encoding;
            result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }       
        doc.LoadHtml(result);
        input = alter (input);
        return doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@title='"+input+"']").InnerText;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }
    string alter(string inputString){
        returnString = "";
        letters = inputString.ToCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<inputString.Length;i++){
            if(letters[i]=='\''){
                returnString = returnString + "&#39;";  
            }else{
                returnString = returnString + letters[i];   
            }
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

The code is accessed by:

```
    search = new Dictionary();
    input = " ";
    temp = " ";
    returnString = "";
    code = Encoding.UTF8;

    search.Translate(input,"en|es",code);
```

This code does work successfully, if you put "Hello" as input, it will return "Hola". However, if you set input as "How are you?" it will return "Cmo ests". I have done research and have discovered that using UTF8 will not display special characters, which I need for Spanish(and other languages). I have read that using UTF16 will fix this error, however, when I write:

```
code = Encoding.UTF16;
```

Another error pops up saying :

```
Assets/GUIScript.cs(26,33): error CS0117: `System.Text.Encoding' does not contain a definition for `UTF16'
```

If anyone knows the code to properly implement UTF16 or to fix my issue with special character, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need UTF16. Spanish characters (and indeed, any Unicode character) can be represented in UTF8. But to answer your direct question, you should use `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding` for UTF16 ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx)).

The problem you're having is somewhere else.

Comment: Whenever I use: code = Encoding.UTF8Encoding; I get an error saying that System.Text.Encoding does not contain a definition for UTF8Encoding. Also, if I do not need UTF16, how can I use UTF8 to get my Spanish chars to show up?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, there is a static property System.Text.Encoding.UTF8. You could also do `new System.Text.UTF8Encoding` instead. In any case, I don't believe this is the problem, I believe there is a bug elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following image, I did check the translator and the encoding. It seems that UTF-8 is the only thing you should use as I was sure about it. and the encoding for the response of the translator as you can see is UTF-8 too. It's the most complete encoding for using natural languages in the world.

[image]

Cheers